# How to solve this AWS Lambda test event issue "Unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"?

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a minor issue when testing my lambda on AWS, this is the JSON I'm sending to my lambda :

```json
{
  "DeliveryPartnerName": "XXXXX",
  "ParentDeliveryPartnerId": 42,
  "BatchSize": 42,
  "SendEmails": true,
  "SendSMS": true,
  "VolumePerBatch": 10
}
```

This is the model used in my C# lambda :

```
public class ExecutionRequest
    {
        public int BatchSize { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryPartnerName { get; set; }
        public int ParentDeliveryPartnerId { get; set; }
        public bool? SendEmails { get; set; }
        public bool? SendSMS { get; set; }
        public int? VolumePerBatch { get; set; }
    }
```

Of course, the main entry of the lambda is decorated with this :

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
```

And the class is used as the first parameter in the FunctionHandler function.

So when I'm running it locally, I don't have any issue with the aws test tool, and when I'm running it on AWS, it throws me this issue and the lambda logic is running correctly with the values specified.

```
Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

This class is used like this :

```
  public class Function
    {
        public async Task FunctionHandler(ExecutionRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => ...
```

Then, in the ConfigureServices, it's registered as a singleton to be injected in the main service and other services if needed

```
services.AddSingleton(input)
```

Then it's used like this :

```
var orders = await orderRepository.GetOrders(request.DeliveryPartnerName);
```

Nugget package used :

- AWSSDK.Core 3.7.12.11
- AWSSDK.Lambda 3.7.13.25
- Amazon.Lambda.Core 2.1
- Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json 2.1.0

Don't forget, **the values are deserialized correctly, but the message returned by AWS is weird**
Did you meet this issue before?  Thank you in advance for your help and I wish you a lovely day

Comment: Please show relevant code. Where are you using this class, what re you doing with it?

Comment: Made some edits to the post, the main issue is the message returned by AWS even if the deserialization is working

Comment: I think that error message typically means the code is trying to JSON.parse undefined (or null or perhaps empty string). That could be because the JSON data was not present in the request or not correctly indicated in the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pops up because your lambda function isn't returning anything, and when it comes time to `JSON.parse` nothing, it throws this error.

If you change your entry-point to return a string or an object, it should work just fine.

As you already noted, your lambda works either way, it's just the AWS Console that throws this error.